# How to make an array of menu items in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in PHP for my menu items:

```
$items = array('Home' => 'URL1', 'Info' => 'URL1', 'Contact' => 'URL3');
```

Now I want to be able to add an extra value to one index at a time, indicating that it is a selected tab.

How would I do that in a fancy way?

Comment: how are the URLs passed. mydomain.com/index.php or just index.php

Answer (score 1):

you could use a multi dimensional array like so

```
$array['home']['url'] = 'url';
$array['home']['selected'] = true;
```

then if a particular url is selected you just set its selected value to true, you could also add other properties to the nav as well then for instance you could add a hidden value

```
$array['home']['hidden'] = true;
```

------- edit

apologies for the terrible formatting im doing this off my mobile phone

Comment: And when you want to fetch the selected one, you have to iterate through the array. And when you want to select something else, you have to iterate over the array, deselect the selected one and select the one you want to be selected.

Comment: @thejh its not ideal, but thats the idea and it solves the problem that the OP has...

Answer (score 0):

You could make an extra variable for it:

```
$items = array('Home' => 'URL1', 'Info' => 'URL1', 'Contact' => 'URL3');
$active_item='Info';
```

Comment: Isn't there a fancier way? I want the active item to be specified in the array itself.

Comment: @Yuri: Depends on whether you want easy-to-maintain and simple or cool-looking/fancy code.